# Azure Powershell error - New-AzureVMConfig : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to create a VM in Azure Powershell along with these piped commands and I'm getting an error. Here is a copy of my command with the error on the bottom. I doubled checked the variables for my setup and they are OK. Also this command came from [this microsoft doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870963.aspx) and I just edited it. Any ideas?

```
PS C:\> New-AzureVMConfig `
 -Name $quorumServerName `
 -InstanceSize Medium `
 -ImageName $winImageName `
 -MediaLocation "$storageAccountContainer$quorumServerName.vhd" `
 -AvailabilitySetName $availabilitySetName `
 -DiskLabel "OS" |
 Add-AzureProvisioningConfig `
     -WindowsDomain `
     -AdminUserName $vmAdminUser `
     -Password $vmAdminPassword `
     -DisableAutomaticUpdates `
     -Domain $domainName `
     -JoinDomain $FQDN `
     -DomainUserName $vmAdminUser `
     -DomainPassword $vmAdminPassword |
     Set-AzureSubnet `
         -SubnetNames $subnetName |
         New-AzureVM `
             -ServiceName $sqlServiceName `
             –AffinityGroup $affinityGroupName `
             -VNetName $virtualNetworkName `
             -DnsSettings $dnsSettings
```

Error:

```
New-AzureVMConfig : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureVMConfig `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureVMConfig], UriFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UriFormatException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzur
   eVMConfigCommand
```

Comment: try to add the -debug parameter to each azure cmdlet you invoke. Maybe you get a more detailed error message.